# ARRAY - Delete max negative element

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

**TASK:** *it is given an array C(15). Delete from the array the max negative element. Write its index. Show the initial and changed arrays.*

**NOTE:** this code write the smallest negative element, which is '-8' in the array.

**NEEDS HELP IN:** I need to change something that it would write the biggest negative element, which is '-5' in the array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int c[15]= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -5, 8, 9 , 10, -7, 12, -8, 14, 15};
int nmaxelement = c[0];
int nmaxelementplace;
int i;

cout<<"The array is: \n";
for (i=0; i<15; i++)
{
    cout<<c[i]<<" ";
}

for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
if (c[i]<nmaxelement)
{
     nmaxelement = c[i];
            nmaxelementplace = i;
}


cout<<"\nNegative max element is "<<nmaxelement<<endl;
cout<<"Its place: "<<nmaxelementplace<<endl;

int k=nmaxelementplace;
int n=15;

cout<<"Array with the deleted element: "<<endl;

for (int i=k; i<n; i++)
    c[i]=c[i+1];
    n=n-1;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
cout<<c[i]<<" ";


return 0;
}
```

Comment: It already does what it's supposed to. It shows -8 which is the smallest element in the array. Do you want to find the smallest number in the newly created array?

Comment: @user2699298 Read the question again. The code doesn't do what it should.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a learning exercise, I wouldn't write code, just the explanation:

- In general, the array is not guaranteed to have negative elements. Therefore, the program should be ready to see two outcomes - (a) when there is at least one negative element, so you can produce the desired output, and (b) when there are no negative elements in the array.
- Keeping the above in mind, your second loop needs to keep two parts of the current state: the `nmaxelement` that you already have, and `bool haveNegatives` which you need to introduce.
- Set `haveNegatives` to `false before the second loop
- Inside the loop, first check if the number `c[i]` is negative. If it is non-negative, move on to the next element (e.g. using the `continue` statement).
- If the number `c[i]` is negative, look at the current value of `haveNegatives`: if it is set to `true`, compare `c[i]` to `nmaxelement`, and change the current value of `nmaxelement` if `c[i]` is greater.
- If `haveNegatives` is `false`, set it to `true`, and also set `haveNegatives` to `c[i]`

When the loop ends, `haveNegatives` will be set to `true` if `nmaxelement` contains the highest negative element of the array; if there are no negative numbers in the array, `nmaxelement` will remain `false`.

Alternatively, you could store the index of the current max negative in a single variable, rather than keeping both the value and the index. In this case, you could set that index to `-1` before the loop, and make a conditional on that index, like this:

```
// Come to this point only when c[i] is negative
if (maxNegativeIndex == -1 || c[i] > c[maxNegativeIndex]) {
    maxNegativeIndex = i;
}
```

Comment: could You give me more info about the bool?

Comment: @Sofie It's a type that lets you store a value of a logical expression - `true` or `false`. If you have not studied `bool`s yet, consider using the alternative approach with `maxNegativeIndex` replacing both the `haveNegatives` and `nmaxelement`.

Comment: @Sofie Did you try it out? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed contains several bugs. For example variable nmaxelementplace was not initialized,
this loop

```
for (int i=k; i<n; i++)
    c[i]=c[i+1];
```

try to access memory beyond the array.

Moreover names of variables do not correspond their meanings. For example in this loop

```
for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
if (c[i]<nmaxelement)
{
     nmaxelement = c[i];
            nmaxelementplace = i;
```

}

the minimum element is searched but the name of the variable that will contain the minimum is nmaxelement.

Also take into account that the array can have no negative elements.